# exportar clases en JS?

Tags: javascript, phaser3

Estoy intentando hacer OOP en JS, pero por alguna razon a la hora de exportar una clase para usarla en otro archivo JS, ese archivo que es una clase tambien me dice que esta declara pero nunca en uso, una vez que importo el la clase de otro archivo, aqui les muestro:

esta es la clase que quiero exportar:

```
export class Player_spaceship extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor() {
    console.log("hola");
}

export hola() {
    console.log("Hola");
}
}
```

ahora en esta clase Scene2, quiero crear el objeto player_spaceship, para eso hay que importarlo, y lo hago asi:

```
import { Player_spaceship } from "./Player_spaceship";
const speed = 2;
const background_speed = 0.5;
const width = 800;
const height = 500;

class Scene2 extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super("Scene2");
        this.points = 0;
    }
```

una vez que importo a player_spaceship, la clase Scene2 se oscurece y me sale que esta declarada la clase pero nunca en uso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacerlo en JS?

Comment: y si estas usando la clase `Scene2` en algun otro archivo, estas crando instancias de esa clase?

Comment: no entiendo muy bien lo que dices

Comment: Scene2 es como una clase principal en donde creo el objeto player_spaceship y aplico todo sus metodos

Comment: No necesitas ni deberias exportar los metodos de una clase, puesto que al exportar la clase lo demas que haga parte de la clase tambien sera usable con ella en otro archivo. por cierto, aquello que describes no se trata de un error, simplemente una alerta de visual studio code, por lo que tu codigo podria ser interpretado correctamente, lo mas probable es que simplemente te falte usar esa clase en tu otro archivo, como ya han dicho los otros usuarios, haz intentado crear una instancia de esa clase en el otro archivo?, si no es asi solo la estas importando pero no usando.

Comment: Recuerda guardar los archivos para poder que veas algun cambio en el codigo, quiza solo te falte guardarlo para que se refresque visual studio code. notese que la instancia de una clase se refiere a la creacion de un objeto en base a la plantilla (clase), usando la palabra reservada new.